# Function return type from a generic and call arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type:

```
type TableItem = {
  name: 'foo',
  address: 'bar',
}
```

I want to call a function with this type as a generic and an array of strings:

```
scanDb<TableItem>('myTableName', ['address'])
```

Can the function's return type combine the generic with the values from the array, so it's like:

```
Pick<TableItem, 'address'>[]
```

The function will work like this:

```
function scanDb<Item>(tableName, onlyAttr) {
  // do something...
  // returns Pick<Item, UnionOfOnlyAttr>[]
}
```

Comment: could you provide an example of how you want to use this `myFunc` in the code?

Comment: TS unfortunately doesn't support *partial type argument inference* as requested in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242); you could work around it with currying like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mL3jeN) but I don't know if it meets your needs.  Alternatively, somewhere you could express the relationship between table name and data type, and then use regular generics like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1EXOw).  Do either of those work for you? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

in typescript generics do not affect the runtime (usually). there is no way to extract MyType inside of function call. it can only be related to types.

I would try to guess and say that you want to do something like this

```
function pick<T extends object, TKey extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: TKey[]): Pick<T, TKey> {
    const result = {} as any;
    for(let k of keys) {
        result[k] = obj[k];
    }
    return result;
}

// usage
const something = pick({a: 10, b: 20}, ['a'])
```

Comment: Yes, I want something similar, except "obj" is not passed to pick(), but comes from a db call... I understand this is not possible. My example is updated.

Comment: updated question requirements sound possible, but more context is required to help you better. There should be some kind of mapping for TsClass<=>db_table_name and maybe you are using some kind of orm that already solves the problem in a good way, without any need to invent magic from your side